# WPF treeview get path of selected node

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following treeview (for example):

-tasks
  -task1
     task2

let's say that the selcted node is 'task2'.
how can I get the full path to this node usin MVVM? it should be 'tasks.task1.task2'.

thanks,
itay

Comment: Check out [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/749178f2-7d02-4504-b667-0de0e37208b7/getting-the-fullpath-from-a-selected-node-of-a-treeview-populated-thru-databinding).

Comment: Hi,I tried your suggestion but I got an exception on the second row:  Unable to cast object of type 'MyModel' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'.